# Bad request - Create Table in Azure Local Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

When I try to create a table in Table Storage (using Azure Local Storage emulator) I get the error *"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."*

The name of the table is according the rules, so what can be happening?!

**Role Configuration:**

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
<Setting name="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

**Create table method:**

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of the SDK are you using?  If you are mixing the Storage Client library 2.0 and the older SDK (pre 1.8) the emulator has a problem.  I ran into this as well and made sure I was using the StorageClient 2.0 library and the Azure SDK 1.8:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/b1b66cc0-5143-41fb-b92e-b03d017ea3c1

Edit:  There maybe ways to get it work with mixing the Storage API with Azure SDK, but this is an easy solution (workaround).

Answer (score 4):

At least the Azure SDK with the replies with the same error messages (400 Bad request) if the table name is invalid (for example underscore in the name).

Answer (score 0):

If the table name has Underscore(_). It throws the same exception. I was getting same error, I removed underscore and it worked perfectly.